# Am I right about this HOC(Higher Order Component) code?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have two questions.

1. First of all, I'm going to start by explaining this algorithm.After the loading page has *loaded* , I implement a  'loading' visual  in store, and I take this as a prop via `props.loading` and  It works.
   Then I move this piece of logic to a  Higher Order Component(HOC).It works too.

   But before I change, `componentDidUpdate()` worked when re-rendering. After I changed to a HOC the `componentDidUpdate()` didn't work because It does not re-render anymore and `componentDidMount()` works. Because Just rendered(not update. just render). Am I right?
2. I don't understand  this part
   `const withLoad = WrappedComponent => props => { };`
   Why should I write `props` here? I don't understand this mechanism. Let me know.

   I think this is multi arrow function. However If so,shouldn't it be exported as  `export default withLoading(hello)(props);` ? But I am using `export default withLoading(hello);` .

```
const withLoad = WrappedComponent => props =>
  props.load ? (
    <div>
      Loading...
    </div>
  ) : (
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  );
```

Comment: That looks ok to me, can we see how you are implementing this?

Comment: I mean Yeah. It's  OK. But I don't know why It is OK ;(

Comment: 1 you're right 2. google for currying, arrow, es6 etc

Comment: Also... notice that <Hello foo={‘bar’} /> is the same ase function Hello({ foo }) {}

Comment: Is mount more efficiency than update?

Comment: @kiki mount will happen only once when the component is mounting , update can happen any time during the component lifecycle. Welcome to SO  btw :) !

Answer (score -1):

1. The `componentDidUpdate` of your original component should work irrespective of whether it is wrapped in a HOC or not , do verify if the props are actually changing to trigger the update. If you are checking if the `componentDidUpdate` of the HOC is called , then pls make sure that the HOC is being updated.
2. Writing the HOC in ES5 format may help you understand the significance of the `props` param in the internal function , your withLoad HOC may be written as

```
      function withLoad(WrappedComponent){
        console.log(WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name ); // App 
        return function(props){ // props of your HOC are consumed here
        if(props.load)
         return (<div>Loading...</div>)
        else
         return (<WrappedComponent {...props} />);
        }
```

so when you use the HOC as `const LoadingApp = withLoad(App)` and later consume this as `<LoadingApp load={true} />` you can see the LoadingApp props being used in the internal function .

Have a look at the [React docs for HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) it will help in clearing up things.